# Как выполнить shell-скрипт как git-alias, но не добавляя сам alias?

Tags: git, shell

Например, есть такой git-alias.

```
[alias]
    root = "!pwd"
```

Его можно использовать в shell-скрипте:

```
echo `git root`
```

Я бы хотел выполнять его "от имени Git", но не регистрируя alias. Как-то так:

```
echo `git run "pwd"`
```

Возможно ли это?

Comment: @borodatych: да все ок, без обид :) Поскольку вопрос разобрали, предлагаю комментарии потереть. Спасибо за интерес к моим вопросам ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно с использованием параметра `git -c`. Перевод из `man git`:

> ```
>    -c <имя>=<значение>
> ```
>
> Передает команде параметр конфигурации. Предоставленное значение будет использовано вместо значения, имеющегося в файлах конфигурации (но никаких постоянных изменений конфигурации не произойдет). Требуется, чтобы <имя> было указано в том же формате, как и в конфигурационных файлах (вложенные ключи разделяются точками: `foo.bar`)
>
> Обратите внимание, что знак `=` можно не использовать (`git -c foo.bar ...`). В таком случае значение переменной будет установлено в логическое `true`. Если указать `=` без значения (`git -c foo.bar= ...`), то переменной будет присвоено значение пустой строки.

**Решение:**

> echo `git root`

например, так:

```
$ cd /tmp; 
$ echo $(git -c alias.root='!pwd' root)
/tmp
```

**обновление**

> echo `git run "pwd"`

можно, например, так:

```
echo $(git -c alias.run='!$1' run "pwd")
```

---

**к слову**

конструкция

```
$(команда)
```

как замена

```
`команда`
```

прописана в [*posix*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) и потому является полностью переносимой, а ввиду её очевидного удобства (при вложенном использовании), имеет смысл именно ею и пользоваться.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я добавил в ответ пример для второй части вопроса.

Comment: прочитайте, например, в `man git` про опцию `-c`. это просто возможность **при выполнении** конкретной команды переопределить (или использовать новое) конфигурационное значение.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а зачем при правке выбросили пример передачи параметра alias-у?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, в общем, синтаксис-то конечно, тот же, но там уже применена возможность передачи параметра alias-у: именно то, о чём вы спрашиваете во второй части вопроса: `git run "pwd"`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, это уже на усмотрение спрашивающего. в вопросе же чёрным по белому написано «не регистрируя alias»? вот я примеры и привёл, как делать, **не регистрируя** alias.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, я бы в свой ответ вообще не включал такие большие выдержки из документации (абзацы). но раз вы считаете нужным включить — то вам и переводить (улыбка).

Comment: man-страницы, вроде бы, никто не переводил ни на какой из языков (ну, по крайней мере, такие переводы мне не известны). а вот всяких руководств и книг по гиту (например, на русском) — по-моему, уже гораздо больше, чем достаточно. если именно книги, то знаю как минимум две: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/ и http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/